# Filemaker: Script "is equal to 1"

Tags: filemaker

I want to write a script in filemaker which returns true if `table::field = 1` for a certain entry, and false otherwise. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A script can return a value with the **Exit Script** step. To return a Boolean value set the step's result to your expression: Table::Field = 1. The Table::Field must be accessible in the current context (i.e. layout). The result will be the Boolean you're looking for (technically it will be a number). To access this value you need to query it with the **Get( ScriptResult )** function.

The way you describe it it doesn't really sound FileMaker, so if this is not the answer you expected, please provide some context for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Set Variable` script step to set a `$$variable` using the calculation engine to return true or false.